# custom response object for model validation in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want custom object in response of API having [required] data annotation on model properties like this:

```
{
   "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
   "issue": [
     {
       "severity": "fatal",
       "code": "required",
       "location": [
         "/f:AllergyIntolerance/f:status"
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

Is it possible to do it or I would have to code it.

Because model validation happens before action is called, is there any way I can do it?

Comment: So you want to have a required annotation for the property of the object you are returning?

Answer (score 0):

To create custom request and respond samples for your api, you can use [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger](https://medium.com/trimble-maps-engineering-blog/customizing-swagger-responses-for-better-api-documentation-affbfafeac8f) and to improve validations on your models you can use [FluentValidations](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/) [Sample](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/fluent-validation-aspnet-core/). Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate your model  in controller,you could try with `TryValidateModel` method as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

I tried as below:

in controller:

```
var model = new TestModel() { Id=1,nestedModels=new List<NestedModel>() { new NestedModel() { Prop1="P11"} } };
            var isvalid=TryValidateModel(model);
            var errorfiledlist = new List<string>();
            if (!isvalid)
            {
                
                foreach (var value in ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var error in value.Errors)
                    {
                        errorfiledlist.Add(MidStrEx(error.ErrorMessage,"The "," field"));
                    }
                }
            }

            var jsonstring = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
           
            foreach (var field in errorfiledlist)
            {
                var oldstr = String.Format("\"{0}\":null", field);
                var newstr = String.Format("\"{0}\":\"required\"", field);
                jsonstring = jsonstring.Replace(oldstr, newstr);
            };

            var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Object>(jsonstring);

            return Ok(obj);
```

MidStrEx method:

```
public static string MidStrEx(string sourse, string startstr, string endstr)
          {
              string result = string.Empty;
              int startindex, endindex;
              try
             {
                 startindex = sourse.IndexOf(startstr);
                  if (startindex == -1)
                      return result;
                 string tmpstr = sourse.Substring(startindex + startstr.Length);
                endindex = tmpstr.IndexOf(endstr);           
                if (endindex == -1)
                     return result;
                 result = tmpstr.Remove(endindex);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 
             }
             return result;
         }
```

Models：

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Prop { get; set; }

        public List<NestedModel> nestedModels { get; set; }=new List<NestedModel>();
    }

    public class NestedModel
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    }
```

The result：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first for simplify define your models like these :

```
public class ResponseModel
{
      public string resourceType { get; set; }
      public List<ResponseIssueModel> issue { get; set; } = new List<ResponseIssueModel>();
}

public class ResponseIssueModel
{
     public string severity { get; set; }
     public string code { get; set; }
     public List<string> locations { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Then on your actions you can return this :

```
var response = new ResponseModel();
response.resourceType = "OperationOutcome";
response.issue.Add(new ResponseIssueModel
{
     severity = "fatal",
     code = "required",
     locations = { "/f:AllergyIntolerance/f:status" }
});
return Ok(response);
```

> you can use Builder Pattern for easy create response object